# Getting all tickets from Zendesk API

Tags: php, api, zendesk

I am trying to get all ticket data from Zendesk using their v2 API - the API is limited to 100 responses per page and then paginated but I cannot seem to cycle through all the pages to get the total number of tickets (and other information)

As I have no idea how many pages there will be I am stuggling to set a loop to deal with this efficiently. At the moment I have used 20 as I know I have less than 2000 tickets:

```
for ($page=1;$page<20;$page++) {
    if ($page==1) {
        $data = curlWrap("/ticket_metrics.json", null, "GET");
    } else {
        if ($data->next_page!="NULL"&&$data->next_page!=""&&$data->next_page!=0) {
            $data = curlWrap("/ticket_metrics.json?page=$page", null, "GET");
        }
    }

    foreach ($data as $ticket) {
        if (is_array($ticket)) {
            foreach ($ticket as $i) {
                $time=$i->reply_time_in_minutes->calendar;
                if ($time!=0 &&$time!="") {
                    $total_time=$total_time+$time;
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



$answer=$total_time/$counter;

print $total_time."/".$counter."=".$answer;
```

How can I get the total number of tickets and the first response time so I can perform this calculation?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `print_r` to see if the ticket count is available in this call? Any clues in the docs?

Comment: There is a field called count but it is giving the "wrong" result so is not that useful really - the docs are bit all over the place, not helped by lots of forum posts with snippets of Git classes and other things confusing the issue

Comment: If you can edit into your question some sample output, plus what the `count` field _does_ contain, that might of help. That said, I wonder if this question might be best pointed at this product's support channel, if it has one.

Comment: I have opened a ticket but not had a reply yet - I will try and add some sample output but it is pretty vast. The data displays fine for the first page but then just loops and shows that first page 20 times so page is never incrementing from what I can see - I now think my PHP is wrong where I am doing the loop as if I use /ticket_metrics.json?page=2 in the browser it gives the correct data. That said, to limit an API to 100  responses and then add pagination is pointless IMO but it is what it is!

Comment: OK. Are Zenddesk tickets public? Please hyperlink in your question, if so, so people don't expend effort on something that may be being solved elsewhere. If your subsequent pages are the same as the first, it sounds like your `page` variable may be wrong. Check the docs on that too?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you still need it but will post in case others have this problem.

The number of tickets is returned in the response as 'count'.  You are also correct that a maximum of 100 records are returned per page - though you can return less.  This page for reference : http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/rest_api/introduction.html

I'd refactor the code to use a while loop until the next_page is 'null' (i think the case was your problem).

```
$page_num = '1';
$total_records = -1;
while ($page != 'null')
{
    //query API return to $data
    $url = "/ticket_metrics.json?page=" . $page_num;
    $data = curlWrap($url, null, "GET");  

    //'count' is returned in json
    if ($total_records < 0)
        $total_records = $data->$count; 
    $page = $data->next_page;

    //add total_time and increase your counter
}
//process your data
```